# SQL UPDATE within BEGIN and END

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, toad

I need to update big table (ACCOUNTS) and change column based on itself.

How do do this?

This query:

```
begin
UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET ACC = '1' where ACC IN ('3');
UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET ACC = '2' where ACC IN ('4');
end
```

Updates only 4 to 2.

Comment: Can you add more information to your question?  Why would only the second update be getting executed?

Comment: My bad this script works too, but I commited it when cursor was on second update, and not on "begin"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For larger tables it is anyway better to perform **only one update**.

You may combine both updates in one as follows:

```
select * from ACCOUNTS;

A
-
1
2
3
4


BEGIN
  update ACCOUNTS
  set ACC = case when ACC = '3' then '1'
                 when ACC = '4' then '2' end
  where ACC in ('3','4'); 
  dbms_output.put_line('rows updated '  || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
/

rows updated 2

select * from ACCOUNTS;

A
-
1
2
1
2
```

Do not forget to `COMMIT`.